# Multistore Add to Cart 302 redirect loop

Tags: magento-1, error, addtocart, redirect

This is an urgent need to fix issue: a two language magento store, english store: add to cart creates a loop with a 302 error. Only happens in english language. website:

> http://negreshop.com

what you think is happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525651/magento-redirect-loop-cart-controller-overide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked your website, the problem also seems to happen on the Spanish version.

Steps to debug:

- switch back to default template and see if it works then, if it's works there is a problem with your template and/or code. You can check the code for adding something to your cart in the template.
- check your settings for redirecting customer to cart, try to change it and see what happens
- check the store secure and unsecure urls, and see if they are correct

Comment: I have deactivated redirect customer to cart and now the product adds to cart BUT I need to redirect the customer to cart...could the problem be with that option activated? Maybe there's an error in te code when redirect the customer to cart. What's the file? Thanks, Akif Gumussu.